# Get the Firefox addon version from a content script

Tags: firefox-addon, content-script

How can I get the Firefox addon version in a content script? The global `self` object is available but it doesn't have a version number.

Answer (score 2):

The addon version is available in the [`self`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/self) module that is only accessible from addon scripts.

```
var self = require('sdk/self');
var version = self.version;
```

You can send the version to your content scripts via message passing on ports. The method for doing this depends on how the content scripts were added, as explained in the [Content Scripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts#Communicating_with_the_add-on) guide.

If you were using [PageMod](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod), you could do this:

**main.js**

```
var pageMods = require("sdk/page-mod");
var self = require("sdk/self");

var pageMod = pageMods.PageMod({
  include: ['*'],
  contentScriptFile: self.data.url("content-script.js"),
  onAttach: function (worker) {
    worker.port.emit('version', self.version);
  }
});
```

**content-script.js**

```
self.port.on('version', function(version){
  alert(version);
});
```

Comment: This does work, but I'm trying to update the version var and that's not working the way my mind thinks it should. For instance, when I do "self.port.on("get-version", ver => { version = ver; alert(version); });" I get an alert with the version number, but the HTML is still 0.0.0, which I used to define the version variable at the beginning of the content script.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `contentScriptOptions` parameter when attaching workers (via *page-mod*, *page-worker*, tab *attach* method, etc.):

Pass the `version` to a content script via `contentScriptOptions` from an addon module (/lib/):

```
var worker=require("sdk/tabs").activeTab.attach({
        contentScriptFile:...,
        contentScriptOptions:{
                version: require("sdk/self").version
        }
});
```

Then obtain the `version` as a property of `self.options` in the content script (/data/):

```
var {version}=self.options;
```

---

To clarify: `self` in the content script is not the same as `self` via `require("sdk/self")` used in an addon module.  The latter is where the addon `version` property is found, not the one in content script.